# How to start multiple processes for a Docker container in a bash script

Tags: bash, docker

I found very strange behaviour when I build and run docker container. I would like to have container with cassandra and ssh.
In my Dockerfile I've got:

```
RUN echo "deb http://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian 20x main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo "deb-src http://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian 20x main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 4BD736A82B5C1B00  
RUN apt-key add ~/.gnupg/pubring.gpg  
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install cassandra
```

And then for ssh

```
RUN apt-get install -y openssh-server
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
RUN echo '{{ docker_ssh_user }}:{{docker_ssh_password}}' | chpasswd
EXPOSE 22
```

And I added start script to run everything I want:

```
USER root
ADD start start
RUN chmod 777 start

CMD ["sh" ,"start"]
```

And here comes problem. When I have start like this below:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/sbin/sshd -D
/usr/sbin/cassandra -f
```

SSH is working well. I can do `ssh root@172.17.0.x`. After I log in container I try to run `cqlsh` to ensure that cassandra is working. But `cassandra` is not started for some reason and I can't access `cqlsh`. I've also checked `/var/log/cassandra/` but it was empty.

In second scenario I change my start script to this:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/sbin/sshd -D & /usr/sbin/cassandra/ -f
```

And I again try to connect `ssh root@172.17.0.x` and then when I run `cqlsh` inside container I have connection to `cqlsh`.

So I was thinking that ampersand `&` is doing some `voodoo` that all works well ?
Why I can't run bash staring script with one command below another?
Or I'm missing something else??

Thanks for reading && helping.

Comment: I wouldn't know. Very strange indeed. But as this seems very bash-related I added the bash tag.

Comment: @qkrijger - can I close self answered question and mark as solved ?

Comment: I don't think so. You should probably answer and accept your own question, based on posts like this on meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93178/my-question-was-answered-in-a-comment-how-do-i-close-the-question

Comment: damn it - I completely missed that you use '&' instead of '&&', which I thought. Check out my article on using supervisor to do this better: http://blog.trifork.com/2014/03/11/using-supervisor-with-docker-to-manage-processes-supporting-image-inheritance/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to my friend linux guru we found the reason of error.

`/usr/sbin/sshd -D` means that `-D` : **When this option is specified, sshd will not detach and does not become a deamon. This allows easy monitoring of sshd**

So in the first script `sshd -D` was blocking next command to run.
In second script I've got `&` which let `sshd -D` go background and then cassandra could start.
Finally I've got this version of script:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/sbin/sshd
/usr/sbin/cassandra -f
```